# conditional add JSX attribute in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So I have this button in JSX:

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" {usersOnCall.indexOf(user) > -1 ? "disabled" : ""}></button>
```

I want the button to be disabled when the conditional is true, I tried above code but it didn't work. Can anybody give me a suggestion how to do it? Many thanks!

Comment: you are not adding disable as attribute, that is your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code accordingly

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={usersOnCall.indexOf(user) > -1 ? true : false}></button>
```

Or you can shorten with

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={(usersOnCall.indexOf(user) > -1)}></button>
```

---

**Update accourding to @Chris's comment**

ES6 option:

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" disabled={usersOnCall.includes(user)}></button>
```

Comment: This is the best option.

Comment: For ES6 I would also add `disabled={usersOnCall.includes(user)}` as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Use `disabled` as a prop as well as `className`. `usersOnCall.indexOf(user) > -1` is already a boolean value and you don't have to return `true` or `false`

```
<button
  className="btn btn-primary"
  disabled={usersOnCall.indexOf(user) > -1}
></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your condition instead of `YOUR_CONDITION`.

```
<button
  disabled={YOUR_CONDITION}>
</button>
```